# What's the rule with religion-spam?

Tags: discussion, scope, users

A new user is asking countless questions which seem to have the goal of proving from Jewish texts that Mohammed was a real prophet. Do we just allow this to go on indefinitely? Personally, I have been enjoying MY a lot less the last few days with all these similar new questions constantly popping up on my screen.

Answer (score 8):

Speaking generally, based on my past experience as a moderator:

When a user persists in behaviors that are contrary to community expectations, including promoting other religions, insulting Judaism, or fighting with other users, the moderators can exercise a special mod-only [ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119098/179) to communicate privately with the user (for the eyes of the user, the mods, and SE staff only) to ask the user to stop. If the user continues to persist in this behavior, the mods can [suspend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean) the account. If the user returns from suspension and continues with the objected-to behavior, the mods may suspend the account again or may delete it.

Comment: Just to note that mods cannot discuss details of mod-messages or suspensions with regular users.

Comment: @DoubleAA How low the great have fallen :)

Comment: איך נפלו גבורים

Answer (score 3):

[Flag as spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032) The system will take care of it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work

Comment: Yes and no. If the post is spam (if it advertises something, e.g. another religion) then flag it as spam. Otherwise, flag it for moderator attention, or whatever other flag applies. (And vote to close the question if it's closureworthy.) [Mods are supposed to be strict about not accepting wrong flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160755) even when another flag would apply. *Slight* pain in the neck, I know, (because now you have to think about which flag you want to use,) but I don't make the rules.